# Error in .local(.Object, ...) : ‘nobs’ or ‘ninputs’ is not a positive integer Calls: cforest ... .local -> new -> initialize -> initialize -> .local

Tags: r, random-forest, job-scheduling, party

I'm trying to schedule R computing job through Slurm on one of my university cluster nodes. The Rscript has codes running random forest by calling the function "cforest" from the library "party".

I got the following error about cforest:

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) :
  ‘nobs’ or ‘ninputs’ is not a positive integer
Calls: cforest ... .local -> new -> initialize -> initialize -> .local
Execution halted
```

What are the reasons that cause above error?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing your code, but it looks like a problem with your data input. `nobs` could be number of observations and since it is not a positive integer, it might be zero.

Comment: See if your training and testing data contains anything. Caret predict(data= .., reference=...) complains with the error you have mentioned, if the references (in this case the testing data) is empty.